# maintaining view state android

Tags: android

Please don't delete it because its a duplicate. I am an android developer with little experience. I have an app with 2 screens. The first has a bunch of options in a `TableLayout` each selected using a `RadioButton`.

What I want to do is, when I select one option and click a `Button` which appears below, the `View` should switch to the next screen showing some related data and when a `Button` is clicked I want it to come back to the same screen but then the rest of the options should be available to me so as to repeat the same process with another one of the options selected.

In short I want to be able to maintain the state of the first screen. I can't seem to be able to decide between using `ViewSwitcher`, `ViewFlipper`, or multiple `Activities` or using a single `Activity` which is what I am doing right now. But as my app gets bigger its very difficult to handle it. Please suggest the best way to do this. I am confused and desperately in need of help because my job depends on it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 activities. Launch the 2nd activity when the user clicks the button. When the user clicks the "back" button (or some other button you offer him) the 2nd activity finishes and the first activity (which was underneath it) is shown.

Note: You've not given us much information, so I can't guarantee that this is the best solution. From what you've said this is the solution I would recommend though. As they say in advertising "Your mileage may vary" ;-)